# Looking for children's fiction book on smuggling in Cornwall

Tags: identification-request

As a teenager, in the late 90s in the UK, I read a fictional book about smuggling, based in Cornwall.
I'm trying to track down this specific book.

The title was something along the lines of "The Smugglers of [Tre-****]" where the final word is a Cornish-styled place name which I cannot recall.
The plot follows the smuggling of goods through caves on the Cornish coast.

Comment: Welcome to the site. First of all, are you trying to identify this particular book or seeking recommendations for similar books? The latter would be [off-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/17), but the former is [fine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info). Btw, that last link includes a checklist that may help to jog your memory for more useful details. When were you a teenager? An approximate date/location of when you read this book would help to narrow the search.

Comment: My impression is that there are quite a few children's books on smuggling in England, and that many of these are set in Cornwall. Do you remember any more details?

Comment: ISFDB has a story called "[The Smugglers of Penrose](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3226321)" by William Bottrell, in a 1997 anthology  "Strange tales of the Cornish Coast".

Comment: _The Smugglers of Mousehole_ is a series, but seems to new. There's also _The Smugglers of Penreen_, but I can't tell if it's a children's book or not.